# F8 runs code in Powershell 5.1 instead of Powershell 6

Tags: powershell

I have started using vscode but am not proficient with it yet!

I installed powershell 6 but each time I write a code and Hit F8 to run a code section, it runs it in powershell integrated console and that turns out to be powershell 5.1 and not powershell 6. 
Is there a way around it?

Comment: What research have you done on this issue before asking where?

Comment: I tried the steps in this blog.
https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-run-powershell-code-in-vscode/

Now select one of the PowerShell terminals and then mark the code you want to execute in the editor. Next, press Ctrl+Shift+P and type "run sel." Then chose Terminal: Run Selected Text In Active Terminal.

The above steps. But I am not able to set a short cut for the action "Run Selected Text In Active Terminal"

Comment: Did you install the PowerShell Extension?

Comment: That article VERY old in terms of VS Code, which us updated very frequently. You should look up on the official VS Code document site the current instructions for running PowerShell: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/vscode/using-vscode?view=powershell-6